# How to get the type of react-bootstrap props

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a Form.Control component where I want to put some default props (in this example the className) how can I find the props that Form.Control uses? (to replace that "props: any" in the FormControl component.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Form, FormControlProps } from "react-bootstrap";

const Styled_FormControl = styled(Form.Control)`
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #828282;
`;

export const FormControl = (props: any) => (
  <Styled_FormControl
    className={`${props.className || ""} form-control`}
    {...props}
  />
);
```

I tried:

```
props: typeof Form.Control
props: typeof Form.Control.props
props: FormControlProps
props: typeof FormControlProps
props: BsPrefixRefForwardingComponent<"input", FormControlProps> & {Feedback: Feedback;}
```

but none work.

It compiles and renders the component currectly but when I try to use it, some of the tags don't work. Like this:

```
import {FormControl} from "./forms";

<FormControl autoFocus as="select" />
```

VS Code shows me this error:

```
Type '{ autoFocus: true; as: "select"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FormControlProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'autoFocus' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FormControlProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
(JSX attribute) autoFocus: true
```

The prop "as" works fine, but the "autoFocus" not.
Here's a list of the sugestions VS Code gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is the `FormControlProps` you already imported, it is the interface for the FormContol component props (Check the [source code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/FormControl.tsx#L13))

Just do it like this:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Form, FormControlProps } from "react-bootstrap";

const Styled_FormControl = styled(Form.Control)`
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: #828282;
`;

export const FormControl: React.FC<React.AllHTMLAttributes & FormControlProps> = props => (
  <Styled_FormControl
    className={`${props.className || ""} form-control`}
    {...props}
  />
);
```

You can replace `AllHTMLAttributes` with `InputHTMLAttributes` or `SelectHTMLAttributes` if you want something specific.

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with another example

Comment: Any idea how to make the ref attribute be happy?  Type '{ value: number; ref: MutableRefObject<any>; className: string; placeholder: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & FormControlProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & FormControlProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'. Did you mean 'href'?